# How to create a record from the belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this association:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todo_lists
  has_one :profile
end
```

todo_list.rb

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And I'm trying to understand the following behavior:

```
todo_list = TodoList.create(name: "list 1")

todo_list.create_user(username: "foo")

todo_list.user
#<User id: 1, username: "foo", created_at: "2016-05-01 07:09:05", updated_at: "2016-05-01 07:09:05">

test_user = todo_list.user

test_user.todo_lists # returns an empty list
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

test_user.todo_lists.create(name: "list 2")

test_user.todo_lists
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<TodoList id: 2, name: "list 2", user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-05-01 07:15:13", updated_at: "2016-05-01 07:15:13">]>
```

Why `#create_user` adds `user` to `todo_list` (`todo_list.user` returns the `user`), but does not reflect the association when `user.todo_lists` is called?

EDITED:

Trying to create a record from the `belongs_to` side in a `one-to-one` relationship works when using `#create_user!`. It still does not hold true when creating a record from the `belongs_to` in a `one-to-many` relationship, even using `#create_user!`.

```
profile = Profile.create(first_name: "user_one")

profile.create_user!(username: "user_one username")

profile.user
=> #<User id: 6, username: "user_one username", created_at: "2016-05-01 18:22:31", updated_at: "2016-05-01 18:22:31">

user_one = profile.user
=> #<User id: 6, username: "user_one username", created_at: "2016-05-01 18:22:31", updated_at: "2016-05-01 18:22:31">

user_one.profile # the relationship was created
=> #<Profile id: 2, first_name: "user_one", user_id: 6, created_at: "2016-05-01 18:22:09", updated_at: "2016-05-01 18:22:31">

todo_list = TodoList.create(name: "a new list")

todo_list.create_user!(username: "user of a new list")

todo_list.user
=> #<User id: 7, username: "user of a new list", created_at: "2016-05-01 18:26:27", updated_at: "2016-05-01 18:26:27">

user_of_new_list = todo_list.user
=> #<User id: 7, username: "user of a new list", created_at: "2016-05-01 18:26:27", updated_at: "2016-05-01 18:26:27">

user_of_new_list.todo_lists #still does not create user from todo_list
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think You have forgotten to save `todo_list`.
Creating user don't save todo_list automaticlly and TodoList have foreign key not User (todo_list.user_id).

Comment: Using `todo_list.save` does work. But why on the other side of the association (`user.todo_lists.create`), the `user.save` is not necessary?

Comment: It is no necessary in other side because, I think, `todo_list` creating with params like: `todo_list.create(user: user), I am not sure in details but the meaning in this.

Comment: Thanks @kunashir, but it still does not make sense. I edited my question to compare the behavior with the `one-to-one` relationship.

Comment: @user3097405, Yes, You are right. According  to the Rails docs http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to - on creating association with belongs_to foreign key must be set.